# In Libroffice calc, is it possible to transform comments into cell content?

Tags: comments, libreoffice-calc

I have an excel spreadsheet which has comments on many cells. I wish to transform these into the cell content in the adjacent column.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly check this:
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=58858
use Comment.Parent.AbsoluteName to check the absoluteName of the cell (is in the form $Sheet1.$A$1) and Comment.String to retrieve comment when you find the cell.
It is a little bit time expensive.